# Table Vs Table Variable

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

I have below mentioned 2 approaches of accomplishing one task.
1st is selecting from Table directly multiple times and 2nd in selecting desired columns from table into table variable first and then using that table variable multiple times. Which one would perform better and why?

```
declare 
        @var1 varchar(10), 
        @var2 varchar(10)

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- 1st approach
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

select  *
from    tab1
where   tab1.col1 in (select tab2.col1 from tab2 where tab2.col2 <> @var1) or
        tab1.col2 in (select tab2.col2 from tab2 where tab2.col3 <> @var2)


----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- 2nd approach
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

declare @tab2 table (col1 varchar(10), col2 varchar(10))
insert into @tab2
select  col1,
        col2
from    tab2

select  *
from    tab1
where   tab1.col1 in (select t.col1 from @tab2 as t where t.col2 <> @var1) or
        tab1.col2 in (select t.col2 from @tab2 as t where t.col3 <> @var2)
```

Comment: Which one does SQL query analysis say performs better?

Comment: @PaulHadfield during test 1st approach was looking better but will it retain it's upper hand when there would be double or triple amount of records in tab2?

Comment: Tell the server *what you want*, not *how to do it*. For a small table, the table probably would be completely loaded in memory so the cost of a second scan should be negligible. For a large table, you're now forcing the database to allocate *additional* storage for it, just because you don't trust the optimizer to do its job. Write simple, understandable code and only start playing around with things if the *measured* performance doesn't meet your performance *goals* (and if you don't have the latter, how will you know when you're "done"?)

Comment: Above some number of records in tab2, the table variable is going to be too large to store in memory, at which point it will swap to disk. Once that happens, the 2d approach should take much longer than the first, since you're effectively writing and reading every record in tab2 twice.

Comment: adding to Damien ,you can try doing a load test and see results

Comment: @EricF Table variable are stored in tempdb.

Comment: @Blam - what's your point? - tempdb is backed by both memory and disk. Old myths like "table variables are always in memory" needed to be gotten rid of a long time ago.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever My point is exactly what I said - table variable are stored in tempdb and that is a correct statement.    What it your point?   How does that statement contribute to a myth that table variables are always in memory?

Comment: @Blam - then I'm still not understanding what the point of your comment was - yes, table variables are stored in tempdb - but what of it? We can make plenty of true but mundane comments but I don't see what that comment was meant to be adding/correcting to EricFs comment.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I wasn't understanding the question. Forget my answer. Please.

I don't think there is any difference of performance between your 2 methods, because the only difference is a tiny request to retrieve your column, which should be negligible.

The bonus that you get with the second approach is that if you change your column names in the future, you won't need to update your script.

PS:
I think your query to retrieve your columns isn't quite right. Y'oure not retrieving columns names here, but datas. I don't know your DBMS, but if it's Oracle, it should be something like :

```
SELECT column_name
FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'MYTABLE'
```

Comment: Tiny request?  What if tab1 had a million rows?

Comment: The tiny request is the one fetching column names. So I don't think it can have millions of columns.

Comment: Where do you get that tab2 is just a list of column names?

Comment: Oh.. My bad.. I didn't understand well.

Answer (score 0):

According to me the first approach will be faster and efficient.
If u see the execution plan, extra cost for table insert gets added into the second approach.

Execution Plan for first approach:

[image]

Execution Plan for second approach:

[image]

Comment: Dear @shavari please see Damien_The_Unbeliever comment,

Answer (score 0):

Why in the world would you think two selects are faster than one?

Why would you not just select col1, col2 from tab1 where ... ?

In both cases you have a select where
A select on table is faster than a select on table varible

So all you have done is added the overhead of inserting into a table variable to get a less efficient select

A table variable is stored in tempdb
Microsoft has all sorts of warnings on use of table variables

```
[Table variable][1]
```

For one not to use for more then 100 rows
It does not have indexes

Really what if tab1 had a million rows and the where limited it to 10
You really think insert a million rows into @tab2 is going to make it faster?